# In R, how to sum all other columns based on value of one column, without specifying column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 401 columns. The 401st column represents the PIN CODE. I want to add all the other 400 columns on the basis of pin code. Can I do this without having to specify all the 400 column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `group_by` `sum`.  With `dplyr`, pass the 'PINCODE' as the grouping variable and apply `sum` with `summarise_all` which gets the sum of all other columns remaining in the data

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(PINCODE) %>%
    summarise_all(sum)
```

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ PINCODE, df1, sum)
```